# find if there exists a zero of a function that's defined by an integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, roots

let $f(x) = \int ^x_0 g(t) dt = \int_0 ^x \frac{t-t^{1/7} -4}{9-t}dt$

be a function find if $ \exists x_0 \in  (0,9) \quad s.t\quad f(x_0)=0$ .

I'm sure that to solve this exercise will be necessary to use the followings : improper integrals,  zeroes theorem,

first of all let's study the function to know in which interval i may apply the zeroes theorem.

For the fundamental theorem of calculus we know that $f'(x) = g(x) =\frac{x-x^{1/7}-4 }{9-x}$

and we need to find the intervals in which the function is monotonically increasing function in the interval $(0,9) $.

therefore $f'(x) > 0 \iff x-x^{1/7}-4 >0$

let's define $ h(x)=x-x^{1/7}-4$

we know that $ h(3) \approx 0.028 >0 , h(2.8) \approx -0.006 <0$

therefore we know that $ \exists x_0 \in (2.8 , 3): h(x_0) = 0$  because the function is  continous and  the values at the endpoints have opposite signs.

$ \implies f$ is surely increasing in the interval (3,9)

now we should find  $ f(3) , f(9)$ to apply again the zeroes theorem. but i can't proceed. i also tried to "approximate" f(3) like that:

$ \int_0 ^x \frac{t-t^{1/7} -4}{9-t}dt$ = $ \int_0^x -1dt + \int_0 ^x \frac{5}{9-t}dt$
$ -\int_0 ^x \frac{ t^{1/7 }}{9-t}dt $

and later i tried to find  two functions $\alpha(x), \beta(x) : $ $\int^x_0 \alpha(t)dt<\int_0 ^x \frac{ t^{1/7 } }{9-t}dt< \beta(x) dt $

but i managed just to find the following functions that can help me with the approximation $\frac{1}{9-t} , \frac{t}{9-t}$, but considering all the improper integrals that will appear using this "approximations" they don't work properly, because we will have different integrals that diverge with different signs, there for i am not able to approximate $f(3)$ even more i don't know how to solve and find the sign of $ f(9)$ because i'm not able to find a solution to the improper integral ( i tried using theorems for the improper integrals like the "  comparison theorem" but i cannot find a solution).

Comment: You've assembled a lot of the right ingredients.  By "zeroes theorem" do you mean the special case of the intermediate value theorem that says if $f$ is continuous and $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are of opposite signs, then there exists a zero of $f$ between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: The root is approximately $x_0=7.90004$.

Comment: @hardmath yes that's the theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if $t\leq 1$, $g(t)=\dfrac{t-t^{1/7}-4}{9-t}\leq \dfrac{2-4}{8}=-\dfrac{1}{4}$, so $$f(1)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^1g(t)dt<0$$

We also have $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 9} \dfrac{g(t)}{h(t)}=5-9^{1/7}<+\infty$, where $h(t)=\dfrac{1}{9-t}$ (with both functions being non-negative near $9$).

Thus, $\displaystyle\int_0^9 g(t)dt$ has the same character as $\displaystyle\int_0^9 \dfrac{1}{9-t}$, that is, it diverges to $+\infty$.

In other words, $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 9} f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 9}  \displaystyle\int_0^x g(t)dt=+\infty $$

Then, there exists $x_0\in (0,9),$ that we may choose bigger than $1$, such that $f(x_0)>0$.

As $g$ is continuous, $f$ is too and Bolzano's Theorem assures there exists $x\in (1,x_0)$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: I think it is IVT  instead of Bolzano.

Comment: No, it is Bolzano (a continuous function that attains positive and negative values in an interval has a root). It doesn't really matter as IVT is a corollary of Bolzano.

Comment: i have a question, if i am sure that g is surely positive in the interval (3,9) , does it give any information about the sign of f in that interval? no i guess

Comment: No, you can say that the integral from $3$ to $9$ of $g$ is positive, but the negative part of $g$ (for example, from $0$ to $1$) may make $f$ negative.

Comment: so i only know in which interval f is surely increasing, to make the first "minoration" for f(1) for t<= 1 do i need to firstly prove that g is an increasing function  as well?

Comment: To prove that $f(1)$ is negative one only has to notice $g$ is negative on $(0,1)$, by directly bounding its expression. Monotony of $g$ or $f$ is never used.

Comment: @JulioPuerta i don't understand how can you substitute t = 1 in the lower bound estimation of f(1)

Comment: $t-t^{1/7}\leq t\leq 1\leq 2$, and $9-t\geq 8$, all using $0\leq t\leq 1$, I did not substitute.

Comment: @JulioPuerta Actually, Bolzano is a corollary of the Intermediate Value Theorem, not the other way around as you had suggested..

Comment: @MarkViola They are equivalent.

Comment: @JulioPuerta How does the IVT follow directly from Bolzano??  Bolzano follows from the IVT.

Comment: Say $c$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, consider $g(x)=f(x)-c$...